# Using Powershell to create wiki pages from an xml file

Tags: powershell, wiki

I'm trying to batch create wiki pages from an xml file, and have found a few posts that I'm trying to combine, such as [this](http://sharepointryan.com/2011/07/25/bulk-creation-of-pages-using-powershell/) one. There's some problem with my code (Sharepoint isn't creating the pages), but it's not giving me an error message. I'm pretty sure this code is over-complicated, but I'm not sure which parts are necessary, and which are extraneous. Thanks for the help.

CODE:

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll'

function CreateTestWiki()
{
[CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$SiteUrl,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [string]$PageTitle,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [string]$PageUrl,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [string]$PageContent,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [string]$PageLayout,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [switch]$CheckIn,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [switch]$Publish,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [switch]$CreateFromXml,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [string]$XmlInput,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][System.Net.NetworkCredential]$credentials
    )
#Region CreateFromXml
if ($CreateFromXml) {
# Read in list of pages from XML
[xml]$pagesXML = Get-Content $($XmlInput)
if ($pagesXML -eq $null) { return }
# Get publishing web
$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($SiteUrl)
$psite = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingSite($site)
$web = $site.OpenWeb()
$pWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($web)
$templateRedirectionPageMarkup = '<%@ Page Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.TemplateRedirectionPage,Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Reference VirtualPath="~TemplatePageUrl" %> <%@ Reference VirtualPath="~masterurl/custom.master" %>';

$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($webUrl)
$ctx.Credentials = $credentials


$wikiPages = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Pages")
$load = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext].GetMethod("Load") 
$listLoad = $load.MakeGenericMethod([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List]) 
$listLoad.Invoke($ctx,@($wikiPages,$null)) 
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

# Loop through each page node to extract filename
$pagesXML.Pages.Page | ForEach-Object {
    $PageTitle = [string]$_.PageTitle
    $PageUrl = [string]$_.PageUrl
    $PageLayout = [string]$_.PageLayout
    $PageContent = [string]$_.PageContent
    $ctype = $psite.ContentTypes[$PageLayout]
    $layouts = $psite.GetPageLayouts($ctype, $true)
    $layout = $layouts[0]
    Write-Host "Creating $($PageTitle)"

    # Create blank page
    $pages = $pWeb.GetPublishingPages($pWeb)
    $page = $pages.Add($PageUrl, $Layout)
    #$newPage = $pWeb.AddPublishingPage($PageUrl,$PageLayout)
    $page.Update()

    # Update the filename to the one specified in the XML
    $item = $page.ListItem
    $item["Title"] = $PageTitle;
    $item["Page Content"] = $PageContent;
    $item.Update()
    # Check-in and publish page
    if ($CheckIn){$item.File.CheckIn("")}
    if ($Publish){$item.File.Publish("");}
} #End ForEach Loop
# Dispose of the web
$web.Dispose()
} #End CreateFromXml
#EndRegion CreateFromXml

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example demonstrates how to create a Wiki pages in SharePoint 2010 using CSOM.

Example

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll'



Function Invoke-LoadMethod() {
param(
   $ClientObject = $(throw "Please provide an Client Object instance on which to invoke the generic method")
) 
   $ctx = $ClientObject.Context
   $load = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext].GetMethod("Load") 
   $type = $ClientObject.GetType()
   $clientObjectLoad = $load.MakeGenericMethod($type) 
   $clientObjectLoad.Invoke($ctx,@($ClientObject,$null))
}


function CreateWikiPage()
{
param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$webUrl,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][System.Net.ICredentials]$credentials,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$pageUrl,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$pageContent
    )
            $templateRedirectionPageMarkup = '<%@ Page Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.TemplateRedirectionPage,Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Reference VirtualPath="~TemplatePageUrl" %> <%@ Reference VirtualPath="~masterurl/custom.master" %>';

            $ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($webUrl)
            $ctx.Credentials = $credentials

            $file = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
            $file.Url = $pageUrl
            $file.Content = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($templateRedirectionPageMarkup)
            $file.Overwrite = $true

            $wikiPages = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Pages")
            $wikiFile = $wikiPages.RootFolder.Files.Add($file)
            Invoke-LoadMethod -ClientObject $wikiFile

            $wikiPage = $wikiFile.ListItemAllFields
            $wikiPage["PublishingPageContent"] = $pageContent
            $wikiPage["PublishingPageLayout"] = "/_catalogs/masterpage/EnterpriseWiki.aspx, Basic Page"
            $wikiPage.Update()
            $ctx.ExecuteQuery();

}




$filePath = "C:\Temp\PagesStructure.xml" 
$UserName = "username"
$webUrl = "https://contoso.intranet.com/kb"
$Password = "password"
$credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($UserName,$Password,$Domain)

[xml]$pagesStructure = Get-Content $filePath
$pagesStructure.Pages.Page | ForEach-Object {
    $PageTitle = [string]$_.PageTitle
    $PageUrl = [string]$_.PageUrl
    $PageContent = [string]$_.PageContent

    Write-Host "Creating $($PageTitle)"
    CreateWikiPage $webUrl $credentials $pageUrl $pageContent
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is it possible to add keywords from the xml file? I know it's more complicated, since it's a multi-value field.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the help

This is what I came up with:

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll'

function CreateWikiPage()
{
param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$webUrl,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][System.Net.NetworkCredential]$credentials,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$pageName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$pageContent,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$XmlInput
    )
            $templateRedirectionPageMarkup = '<%@ Page Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.TemplateRedirectionPage,Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Reference VirtualPath="~TemplatePageUrl" %> <%@ Reference VirtualPath="~masterurl/custom.master" %>';

            $ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($webUrl)
            $ctx.Credentials = $credentials


            $wikiPages = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Pages")
            $load = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext].GetMethod("Load") 
            $listLoad = $load.MakeGenericMethod([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List]) 
            $listLoad.Invoke($ctx,@($wikiPages,$null)) 
            $ctx.ExecuteQuery()


            $file = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
            $file.Url = $pageName+='.aspx'
            $file.Content = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($templateRedirectionPageMarkup)
            $file.Overwrite = $true


            $wikiFile = $wikiPages.RootFolder.Files.Add($file)
            $fileLoad = $load.MakeGenericMethod([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File]) 
            $fileLoad.Invoke($ctx,@($wikiFile,$null))

            $wikiPage = $wikiFile.ListItemAllFields
            $wikiPage["PublishingPageContent"] = $pageContent
            $wikiPage["PublishingPageLayout"] = "/_catalogs/masterpage/EnterpriseWiki.aspx, Basic Page"
            $wikiPage.Update()
            $ctx.ExecuteQuery();

}

[xml]$pagesXML = Get-Content $('c:\temp\testWiki.xml')
if ($pagesXML -eq $null) { return }

$pagesXML.Pages.Page | ForEach-Object {
    if($_.PageName -eq $_PageTitle)
    {
        Write-Host "Page ($PageName) exists."
        break;
    }
    $credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential('username', 'password','url')
    $PageName = [string]$_.PageTitle
    $PageContent = [string]$_.PageContent
    CreateWikiPage $webUrl $credentials $pageName $pageContent
    Write-Host "Creating $($PageName)"
} #End ForEach Loop
```