# How Do You Edit Pages Using The Client Side Object Model?

Tags: development, client-object-model, page-layout

Im using the C#  CSOM object for Sharepoint 2013. I want to edit the homepage of a site so i can add some custom content to it. I want to be able to add some custom text and some web parts in the future if i ever need them. So far i have the following code

```
        using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://sharepointserver/site1"))
        {
            var pagesList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Site Pages");
            context.Load(pagesList);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            var rootcontents = pagesList.RootFolder.Files;
            context.Load(rootcontents);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            var homepage = rootcontents[1];
        }
```

I had expected that i could go homepage.content = "abc"; there is no option to do this with the homepage object. I have the correct page that i want in this homepage object but i cant figure out how to add custom content to the page using this objects.

Comment: Maybe this will help you get started, http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/98741/using-powershell-to-create-wiki-pages-from-an-xml-file

Comment: This is powershell, i need to be  able to do it using C#

Comment: They are using Powershell and CSOM, it might help you understand what needs to be done in C# CSOM is what I was getting at, and was a recent example of someone wanting to do the same thing, add/edit wiki pages from CSOM.

Comment: First, you need to find out what is the home page of the current web which i don't think you are doing in your code.! SPWeb.RootFolder.WelcomePage will give you the page that you need to update. I don't know how to mange the content and components of a site page from code!