# importing HTML into Sharepoint

Tags: html, xml, import, document-converter

I'm successfully importing an XML files into Sharepoint as wiki pages, following [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/98741/using-powershell-to-create-wiki-pages-from-an-xml-file) template. However, the HTML that's in the XML is being imported as text, so my page reads "`<p>Hello World</p>...`". Is there a way to tell Sharepoint to interpret the field as HTML?

Note: in order to import the text using XML, I had to convert '<' and '>' into 
`&#60;`and `&#62;`. I did convert those characters back using `replace`

Answer (score 0):

When using html code into XML files, you usually need to use the "CDATA tag" stuff.

This link can be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean

Comment: Hi @william Bernal, Thanks for the input, but I want to do the opposite of what I understand CDATA to do. Sharepoint is currently interpreting all my markup as plain text, but I WANT it to be interpreted as HTML.